# How to prettyprint Elixir errors

Tags: elixir, pretty-print

So I am attempting to work on an Elixir-based project.  However, any error in Elixir does not throw a human readable error code, but nested structures (nested in multiple types of brackets) of keys and values.  It is difficult to discern what is nested in where.  As an example:

```
no match of right hand side value: {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: %{"error" => %{"index" => "comments", "index_uuid" => "_na_", "reason" => "no such index [comments]", "resource.id" => "comments", "resource.type" => "index_or_alias", "root_cause" => [%{"index" => "comments", "index_uuid" => "_na_", "reason" => "no such index [comments]", "resource.id" => "comments", "resource.type" => "index_or_alias", "type" => "index_not_found_exception"}], "type" => "index_not_found_exception"}, "status" => 404}, headers: [{"content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}, {"content-length", "377"}], request: %HTTPoison.Request{body: "{\"_source\":false,\"from\":0,\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":{\"range\":{\"posted_at\":{\"gt\":\"now-1w\"}}},\"must_not\":[{\"terms\":{\"image_tag_ids\":[4,7]}},{\"term\":{\"hidden_from_users\":true}}]}},\"size\":6,\"sort\":{\"posted_at\":\"desc\"},\"track_total_hits\":true}", headers: [{"Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}], method: :post, options: [], params: %{}, url: "http://elasticsearch:9200/comments/_search"}, request_url: "http://elasticsearch:9200/comments/_search", status_code: 404}}
```

Note that I am not asking about *this error*; I am asking about *this style of error.*

Is there a standard way to 'prettyprint' an Elixir error?

Answer (score 0):

These can indeed be hard to read.  But keep in mind that returning the full structure in the error is often done on purpose: you can often literally copy and paste the value into an `iex` session, for example, and use it to test the problematic code. In other words, the errors are often meant *to be read by humans*.

However, there are a couple techniques that may be helpful to you.  The first is the simple [inspect/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#inspect/2) function: it can limit the size of the message and it stringifies complex structures (which can be very useful for logging).  It has a `pretty` option, which may be what you're after. There are a few other options you may want to try.

```
inspect(some_error, pretty: true)
```

The other technique is more specific: sometimes you have to "unwrap" errors to make them more readable.  Sometimes there are helpers for this (think Phoenix view-helpers that format Ecto errors or [Ecto.Changeset.traverse_errors/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#traverse_errors/2) are examples of helper functions that deal with making errors more readable).  There is not "one-size-fits-all" shape of an error message -- they are usually specific to the use case.

Lastly, it's worthy mentioning that pattern matching especially can help you control the flow of your code so that you are more carefully guarding what is considered a success vs. failure, and that can help you sort through different kinds of errors.